# Javascript For..In loop executing both the if and else statement

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I have this if statement with an else block and they are both inside a for in loop. When I execute this it always return both the value from the if statement and the else statement. Shouldn't it only go to the else block when the if statement is false?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to begin</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

const moodList = {
    sad: {
        quotes: ['this is a sad quote',
                 'this is a sad quote number 2',
                 'this is a sad quote number 3'
                ]
    },
    happy: {
        quotes: ['this is a happy quote',
                 'this is a happy quote number 2',
                 'this is a happy quote number 3'
                ]
    }
}

function myFunction() {

  let moodInput = prompt('Enter a feeling');

  for (var key in moodList) {
    if (moodInput.includes(key)) {
      console.log('you got a result!');
    } else {
      console.log('nothing');
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not. Why do you think it is? There's no way it's doing both at the same time. It may be doing each of them during different iterations of the loops, but that's different.

Comment: You are looping each key. If I input sad you will get once true and once false for your IF.

Comment: you are running the loop over your moodList - so you check the user input against all possibilities - it will log for every modd, if its the one you entered or not

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a loop over the object, you could check to see if the value entered is a key on the object:

```
if (moodList[moodInput]) {
  console.log('you got a result!');
} else {
  console.log('nothing');
}
```

Updated Code:

```js
const moodList = {
  sad: {
    quotes: ['this is a sad quote',
      'this is a sad quote number 2',
      'this is a sad quote number 3'
    ]
  },
  happy: {
    quotes: ['this is a happy quote',
      'this is a happy quote number 2',
      'this is a happy quote number 3'
    ]
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  let moodInput = prompt('Enter a feeling');
  if (moodList[moodInput]) {
    console.log('you got a result!');
  } else {
    console.log('nothing');
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to begin</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the key and check if the key is in the object with the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```js
const moodList = {
    sad: {
        quotes: ['this is a sad quote',
                 'this is a sad quote number 2',
                 'this is a sad quote number 3'
                ]
    },
    happy: {
        quotes: ['this is a happy quote',
                 'this is a happy quote number 2',
                 'this is a happy quote number 3'
                ]
    }
};

function myFunction() {
    let moodInput = prompt('Enter a feeling');

    if (moodInput in moodList) {
        console.log('you got a result!');
    } else {
        console.log('nothing');
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to begin</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Great thanks! I'm an absolute beginner and continue to forget when to use and when not to use loops. Your example works great thanks.